# how to change jquery datepicker to US datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my datepicker div and I want to change this datepicker to US datepicker.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $(document).on("click", "#datetimepicker3", function (e) {

  //  $('#datetimepicker2').focus();
  $('#datetimepicker2 , #datetimepicker3')
    .datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      // endDate: '+0d',
      format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
      todayHighlight: true,
      //startDate: '+0d'
      startDate: Date().toLocaleString()
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
      $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('hide');
      $('#GuestSearchForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'Servicedate');
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 home-date">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datetimepicker3" align="center">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Servicedate" id="datetimepicker2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select date" readonly>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the documentation? I would assume the default format is US - what happens if you remove the `format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the format argument use

```
format : 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

Comment: k but i need  calander also based on US

Comment: what do you mean based on US? Please explain better

Comment: Actually i have timeslots concept based on US calander user select his service based on US Calandar nothing but US timezone and right now it is working based on UTC but i need EST